# Dynamically updating dictionary on text entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Lets say I have a text box into which I am entering text. Under it I have a div which displays the entered text, highlighting words based on whether they have been correctly spelt or not, as follows:

```
var validity = 
{
    "a": true,
    "aa": false,
    "aaa": false
};

document.getElementById("edit").addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    text_array = this.value.split(" ");

    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i< text_array.length; i++) {  
        output.push('<span class="' + group(validity[text_array[i]]) + '">' + text_array[i] + '</span>');
    }

    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = output.join(" ");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/barra/aC9nt/12/

I also have a php script which can be passed an array of words and which replies via json conveying if they are valid or not.

I wish to make a request to this script in a dynamic fashion as text is entered. However, the ajax call to the php script is asynchronous and before I even get the first reply from the server, a new request to the script might well be made as the user quickly enters text into the box. How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a timeout to only send the request after typing has stopped for x miliseconds. Try this:

```
var timer;
document.getElementById("edit").addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        text_array = this.value.split(" ");

        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0; i< text_array.length; i++) {  
            output.push('<span class="' + group(validity[text_array[i]]) + '">' + text_array[i] + '</span>');
        }

        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = output.join(" ");

        // send ajax request with the values
    }, 500);
});
```

This will prevent the request being made until 500ms after typing has stopped. You can adjust that value to make it more/less responsive as needed.

Comment: Will there be any issues if we say that the server takes 1 second to reply, besides the fact that the div text will be slow to update?

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue with that, so long as you show the user that their input has been recognised and a response is being generated. For example, a wait spinner would work well.

Answer (score 2):

use `setTimeout()` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

```
var timer = null;

$('#testInput').on('keyup',function(event){
    $this = $(this);
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        var input = $this.val();
        //this is where you would post your data to the server
        alert(input);
    }, 500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3sMw/1/

Comment: Will there be any issues if we say that the server takes 1 second to reply, besides the fact that the div text will be slow to update?

Comment: See @RoryMcCrossan's answer to the same question

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag to indicate that an Ajax request is pending. When you want to send a request check the flag, if it is set do not send the Ajax request else set the flag and send the request. When the request completes clear the flag.

Comment: If the user enters "a" the result is an ajax request. But while this request is being made say the user completes "a" by typing "s", wont the flag stop "as" being requested?

Comment: Always send all the input text to PHP for processing on a periodic basis, say every 100 ms. Show the incorrect highlights when the Ajax request completes. This allows the user to backspace and edit his input (assuming you allow it). This does result in short intervals when the two text boxes are not coherent. I do not think you can avoid that unless you prevent user input while the Ajax request is pending.